# How to add borders to headings in AsciiDoctor-pdf PDF output

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

How to add borders to headings in AsciiDoctor-pdf PDF output.

(I am not an English speaker. Ask me if any expressions are difficult to understand).

I am a high school student and I am using AsciiDoctor-PDF to create documents for other students to look at.

https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/heading/#level

[documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th5RI.png)

I want to put a border around a heading using the `border` in the URL above.

The border around the heading would look like the image below.
The top text is on level 2 and the bottom text is on level 3 in the image.

[output-pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0G9J.png)

What should I do?

```yaml
heading:
  h1_font_size: floor($base_font_size * 2.4)
  h2:
    font_size: floor($base_font_size * 2.4)
    border-width: [0.75, 0, 2, 0]
    border-color: 000000
```

Comment: Are you sure that your headings are levels 2 and 3? Try adding a style for h3 and see if the border appears. Your style worked for me, applying borders to h2 headings but not for smaller headings.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but I suspect that your impression of the heading level is incorrect.

To demonstrate that adding borders to heading works, here's a simple document:

```
= Document
:pdf-theme: ./pdf-theme.yml

Lorem ipsum...

== Section 1

This is section 1.

=== Subsection A

Section 1 has a subsection.

== Section 2

This is section 2.
```

And here is the content of `pdf-theme.yml`:

```
extends: default-with-font-fallbacks
heading:
  h2:
    font-size: floor($base_font_size * 2.4)
    border-color: #ff0000
    border-width: 2pt
  h3:
    font-size: 22pt
```

That renders like this:

[image]

I suspect that in your document, the heading you are trying to style is a level 3 or level 4 heading, which is why you do not see the border. You have only added the border style for level 2 headings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It was h2 that I was trying to add boder to.

I will give you the URL of the program on GitHub.

　　　This is the heading "Introduction" in h2.
https://github.com/oskfesfinance/finance-book/blob/e4f54f20a1a98a028dc608425dfeb87e52cc4b23/index.adoc?plain=1#L89

　　　The output is page 4 of the PDF file below.
https://oskfesfinance.github.io/finance-book/pdf/output.pdf

　　　The border is defined at the URL location below.
https://github.com/oskfesfinance/finance-book/blob/e4f54f20a1a98a028dc608425dfeb87e52cc4b23/theme/book.yml#L57

Comment: I am using GitHub Actions to generate the PDF. If you know why the borders are not rendered, would you please let me know?